# Android: How to implement simple "rate it" preferences button?

Tags: android, preference

I've googled and searched for an answer to my question but all I can find is people asking about rating systems that pop up a dialogue after a number of launches.

My application is for a live wallpaper so I expect most people to launch and set it once.

I just want a preference button that takes users as directly as possible to the app rating screen.

Can anyone suggest the best way to accomplish this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code you are looking for

https://github.com/codechimp-org/AppRater

Add this library in your project and you should be set.

Comment: I have used this before and works great. It uses SharedPreferences.

Comment: This is what I've already found in my searches, I'm looking for a simple preference item, not an invasive popup window.

Comment: It looks like the code I need is within this library, I'll root around in it and see if I can get what I need working, thank you for the link!